# Sharepoint REST getfilebyid sometimes returns - 404 - not found

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I'm trying to download the file by it's unique id (GUID) and in 99% it's working fine, but there some cases where I'm getting http not found - 404. But I know that file is exists and I know it's unique id, from the metadata I got from the document library.
How file can't be found if I have it's metadata in hands ?

I'm doing the next (Java):

```
//itemID is taken from the library listing (using web service) as uniqueid (guid)
String requestUrl = site + "/_api/web/GetFileById('" + itemID.substring(1, itemID.lastIndexOf('}')) + "')/$value"; //Remove {} from the unique id
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(requestUrl);
// setting auth credentials to the request.
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(60000).build();
request.setConfig(requestConfig);
request.addHeader("accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
HttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
int iRet = result.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); //Here iRet = 404, sometimes.
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share some of your code that could help us reproduce or look at the problem? With the information you have given I might as well say the earth's magnetic field alignment is to blame.

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Seems that no answer for this, even from Microsoft folks :(

Answer (score 0):

From previous experience I would look for a lock by concurrent connections. I see you have a 60 s timeout (setConnectTimeout(60000)) in your code. For instance, have you tried if having a single query returns a valid result, and after (say 120s) you try twice within the 60s timeout, it returns the 404?

Comment: Hi, there's no concurrent connections, on many documents the code is running fine, but on some documents it's never , just returns 404.